# Criar Observer na classe Mage_Core_Model_App para a função run

Tags: php, magento

Ao olhar para a classe `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php`, temos a seguinte função:

```
public function run($params)
    {
        $options = isset($params['options']) ? $params['options'] : array();
        $this->baseInit($options);
        Mage::register('application_params', $params);

        if ($this->_cache->processRequest()) {
            $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
        } else {
            $this->_initModules();
            $this->loadAreaPart(Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_GLOBAL, Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::PART_EVENTS);

            if ($this->_config->isLocalConfigLoaded()) {
                $scopeCode = isset($params['scope_code']) ? $params['scope_code'] : '';
                $scopeType = isset($params['scope_type']) ? $params['scope_type'] : 'store';
                $this->_initCurrentStore($scopeCode, $scopeType);
                $this->_initRequest();
                Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllDataUpdates();
            }

            $this->getFrontController()->dispatch();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Para se adicionar um `event/observer` usamos o seguinte codigo:

```
<events>
  <EVENT_TO_HOOK>
    <observers>
      <module>
        <type>singleton</type>
        <class>company_module_model_observer</class>
        <method>methodToCall</method>
      </module>
    </observers>
  </EVENT_TO_HOOK>     
</events>
```

Qual o evento que devemos adicionar para observarmos a função `run` da classe `Mage_Core_Model_App`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível observar a função `run` da classe `Mage_Core_Model_App` através de um evento.

O único evento disparado nessa classe era o `application_clean_cache`. Confira a lista completa em http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/

Mas a listagem acima vale para a versão 1.8 - esse evento mencionado acima já não existe mais.

Um evento é disparado através do método `dispatchEvent`. Por exemplo:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('application_clean_cache', array('tags' => $tags));
```

(fonte: http://freegento.com/doc/d8/d98/_app_8php-source.html#l01084)

No código da função `run` em `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php`, postado na pergunta, vemos que não há nenhuma chamada a `Mage::dispatchEvent`. Isso significa que nenhum evento é disparado e, portanto, não há nenhum evento para ser observado e capturado aí.

A alternativa é [estender a classe e fazer um *override* da função](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method).

Ou então (embora não recomendável) alterar o código da função no Magento, acrescentando o disparo de um evento com `dispatchEvent`...